# Function/way to redirect to specific page whenever a specific text occurs on homepage?

Tags: functions, homepage

On my Homepage

when ever a specific text is displayed, it should redirect to another page?

can it be done via functions? how?
if not via javascript? how?

https://wpt1.ide4.bid/  Please go to this page, when you fill the form up, it's easy.

Below you will see the text "Thank You For scheduling 22" after the form is filled up.

[image]

when the text "Thank You For scheduling 22"  comes it should be redirected to
https://wpt1.ide4.bid/thank-you/

Please help me

Comment: it should be done via javascript because after you have your text on the homepage it is too late to do a php redirect due to headers already being sent.

Comment: @Ovidash Please show me a path how to do it

Comment: First I need an example of what would trigger the behaviour. Paste some text as it would appear on page, and let me know which word / phrase would trigger the redirection.

Comment: @Ovidash Please check my updated question with image

Comment: is that thank you message in a div? What class or id has that div? And how does it appear on page? Via ajax or is it always on the page when you visit the page?

Comment: @Ovidash it inside 

<div class="iconed-text">
      <a href="https://wpt1.ide4.bid/thank-you/" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
        Thank You For scheduling 22
      </a>
    </div>

Comment: @Ovidash its loaded via ajax i think , it an embeded form from https://calendly.com/majeem/15min
Please help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78773/discussion-between-ovidash-and-nimesh).

Comment: That page is stuck in a infinite loop!! Can't help much without having a look. How the form submission is being handled? Custom code or plugin?

Comment: Never mind @Nimesh, I see that on  your website, you have an iframe loading the calendly website. This simply will not work. You cannot have events triggered on your website based on what happens on an iframe that loads an url that is not on the same domain, unless calendly is kind enough to make an exception for you. So the short answer, you cannot do it with what you have now.

Comment: @Abhik All the codes are removed now Please check now the Form is embeded 
from calendly.com